# Get updated values to wordpress posts

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have created a plugin to get some data from a API. I have created a custom post type and included the data retrieved from the API to the posts. My code for plugin is as below

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Experts
 * Plugin URI: https://****.**
 * Description: Wordpress plugin for experts.
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: My name
 * Author URI: https://****.**
 */

if (!defined('ABSPATH'))
{
    die;
}

class ExpertsPlugin 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        add_action('init',array($this, 'custom_post_type'));
    }

    function expert_activate()
    {
        $this->custom_post_type();
        flush_rewrite_rules();
        $this-> get_experts_from_api();
    }

    function expert_deactivate()
    {   
        flush_rewrite_rules();   
    }

    function expert_uninstall()
    {

    }

    function custom_post_type()
    {
        register_post_type('expert',['public' => true, 'label' => 'Experts', 'capability_type' => 'post']);
    }

    function get_experts_from_api()
    {
        $experts = [];
        $results = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_remote_get('https://api.****.**/v1/users/profiles?get=10'));
        $results = json_decode($results);
        $experts[] = $results;
        foreach($experts[0] as $expert)
        {
            foreach($expert as $profile)
         {
            $expert_slug = sanitize_title($profile->userId);

            $inserted_expert = wp_insert_post([
                'post_name' => $expert_slug,
                'post_title' => $expert_slug,
                'post_type' => 'expert',
                'post_status' => 'publish'
            ]);

            if(is_wp_error($inserted_expert))
            {
                continue;
            }
         }
        }

    }

}

if(class_exists('ExpertsPlugin '))
{
    $expertsPlugin = new ExpertsPlugin ();
}

//activation
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,array($expertsPlugin , 'expert_activate'));

//deactivation
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__,array($expertsPlugin , 'expert_deactivate'));

//uninstall
register_uninstall_hook(__FILE__,array($expertsPlugin , 'expert_uninstall'));
```

This plugin works correctly. My issue is because i'm only calling the `get_experts_from_api()` when activating the plugin, i cannot get new values if the data in the API is updated. How can i resolve that issue.

One thing i tried is calling the function in the constructor like this

```
function __construct()
{
    add_action('init',array($this, 'custom_post_type'));
    add_action('init',array($this, 'get_experts_from_api'));
}
```

But using this approach , the function calls everytime i refresh the admin page, and also duplicates the data.

How can i prevent duplication of data and what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Preventing duplicate posts is your own responsibility in cases like this. You need to find a way to figure out if a post for one of the records/items you get from that API already exists - and if so, you need to specify the post id as part of your parameters you feed to `wp_insert_post`, then it will update the existing one.

Comment: To have this automatically triggered, either look into https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/, or set up a _real_ cron on your server. (WP cron depends on someone actually visiting your site, so if you need a reliable interval or guaranteed execution, you will need to go with the latter.)

Comment: @CBroe So calling the add_action for get_experts_from_api from the constructor is fine?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, data updates would be originated at the source and sent to your site via webhook, I think. If that capacity isn't available from the API you're using, then you'll have to depend on other means. Which one of the latter you choose may in turn depend on particular characteristics of your installation and the application, as well as of the API.

It could be that refreshing as frequently as anyone visits the site (not just admin, if you're using 'init'), will be adequate for your purposes, and not cause any significant issues. Or it could create issues of various types. If so, you might need to restrict the requests to particular pages or other contexts, or depend on a cron job or other form of external activation.

In the meantime, simply to avoid redundant updates within the current framework, you might get by with something like this in your code (obviously untested):

```
        $expert_slug = sanitize_title($profile->userId);

        //check for post and go to next if found
        if ( get_page_by_path( $expert_slug, OBJECT, 'expert' ) ) {

             // 'expert' - post with same slug already exists, so
             continue;

        }

        $inserted_expert = wp_insert_post([
            'post_name' => $expert_slug,
            'post_title' => $expert_slug,
            'post_type' => 'expert',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        ]);

        //etc.
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_path/